# How can I add canonical tag on certain links on Ezpublish 4.4

Tags: ezpublish

I would like to add a canonical tag to an article on my website, but Ezpublish 4.4 auto generate url and i've found no way to customize them.

Is There a way to activate canonical tag on the article of my choice on Ezpublish 4.4 ?

Comment: Would you mind being a bit more precise on what you need ? Why are you thinking of canonical links ? Does it mean that contents can have multiple locations ?

Answer (score 0):

If your canonical link is your main_node :

try this :

```
{$current_node.main_node.url_alias|ezurl()}
```